# I wanted to simplify menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there a way to simplify this?

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    $("#bt1").on("click", function () {
        $(this).css("background-image", "url(css/fondos/fondotopActivo.png)");
        $("#bt2").css("background-image", "");
        $("#bt3").css("background-image", "");
        $("#bt4").css("background-image", "");
        $("#bt5").css("background-image", "");
        $("#bt6").css("background-image", "");
        $("#bt7").css("background-image", "");
    });

    $("#bt2").on("click", function () {
        $(this).css("background-image", "url(css/fondos/fondotopActivo.png)");
        $("#bt1").css("background-image", "");
        $("#bt3").css("background-image", "");
        $("#bt4").css("background-image", "");
        $("#bt5").css("background-image", "");
        $("#bt6").css("background-image", "");
        $("#bt7").css("background-image", "");
    });

    $("#bt3").on("click", function () {
        $(this).css("background-image", "url(css/fondos/fondotopActivo.png)");
        $("#bt1").css("background-image", "");
        $("#bt2").css("background-image", "");
        $("#bt4").css("background-image", "");
        $("#bt5").css("background-image", "");
        $("#bt6").css("background-image", "");
        $("#bt7").css("background-image", "");
    });

    $("#bt4").on("click", function () {
        $(this).css("background-image", "url(css/fondos/fondotopActivo.png)");
        $("#bt1").css("background-image", "");
        $("#bt2").css("background-image", "");
        $("#bt3").css("background-image", "");
        $("#bt5").css("background-image", "");
        $("#bt6").css("background-image", "");
        $("#bt7").css("background-image", "");
    });

    $("#bt5").on("click", function () {
        $(this).css("background-image", "url(css/fondos/fondotopActivo.png)");
        $("#bt1").css("background-image", "");
        $("#bt2").css("background-image", "");
        $("#bt4").css("background-image", "");
        $("#bt3").css("background-image", "");
        $("#bt6").css("background-image", "");
        $("#bt7").css("background-image", "");
    });

    $("#bt6").on("click", function () {
        $(this).css("background-image", "url(css/fondos/fondotopActivo.png)");
        $("#bt1").css("background-image", "");
        $("#bt2").css("background-image", "");
        $("#bt4").css("background-image", "");
        $("#bt5").css("background-image", "");
        $("#bt3").css("background-image", "");
        $("#bt7").css("background-image", "");
    });

    $("#bt7").on("click", function () {
        $(this).css("background-image", "url(css/fondos/fondotopActivo.png)");
        $("#bt1").css("background-image", "");
        $("#bt2").css("background-image", "");
        $("#bt4").css("background-image", "");
        $("#bt5").css("background-image", "");
        $("#bt6").css("background-image", "");
        $("#bt3").css("background-image", "");
    });
});
```

Its working OK but I want to keep it lighter.

Comment: +1 for realizing what you have isn't great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
  var $allBts =  $("[id^=bt]");
  $allBts.on("click", function () {
        $allBts.css("background-image","");
        $(this).css("background-image","url(css/fondos/fondotopActivo.png)");
   });
```

or

```
   $allBts.on("click", function () {
        $allBts.not($(this).css("background-image","url(css/fondos/fondotopActivo.png)")).css("background-image","");
   });
```

This uses [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) that matches the element based on a starting attribute value, here an id. But you should make sure to use a context where these elements reside as a parent container inorder to avoid selection of undesired element. Or combine them with their type like ex a `div` inside a container `wrapper` then

```
$("div[id^=bt]")
```

or more specific:

```
$('.wrapper').find("div[id^=bt]");
```

*But i would suggest if possible provide all of them a common class name and use a class selector, because it will be faster than an attribute selector.*

Comment: Excellent, Thank you so much, this is so helpful that I just learned something new